# how do I get the variable name of a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to read the name of an object of type list. i.e.

`myList <- list("foo","foo1")`

The way I normally read object names is:

`deparse(substitute(myList))`

however in case of this list it returns:

> "list(\"foo\", \"foo1\")"

The result I want is "myList". Can anyone help?

Comment: What is wrong with `as.character(substitute(..`

Comment: ups I'm sorry that actually gave me the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how I'd read a function actually returns the desired result unlikely I mentioned first.

```
 as.character(substitute(myList))
```